# JavaScript Multiple element object movment

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to move the whole car object with its different body elements and their attributes, but all of the elements are moving in different speeds instead of the whole car moving in one speed.

Any help with this would be great.

I am also using a random number value for the speed.

Here is the code:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(p) {
    //moving everything 
    this.direction = p.direction || 1;

    //wheel constructor
    this.x = p.x || 130;
    this.y = p.y || 160;
    this.wheelSize = p.wheelSize || 15;
    this.WHcolour = p.WHcolour || "black";

    //body constructor
    this.carW = p.carW || 130;
    this.carH = p.carH || 50;
    this.Ccolour = p.Ccolour || "red";
    //window constructor 
    this.windowW = p.windowW || 25;
    this.windowH = p.windowH || 15;
    this.Wcolour = p.Wcolour || "blue";

    //car number 
    this.carNum = p.carNum || 1;
  }
  
  draw() {
    //draw wheel 1
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.arc(this.x, this.y, this.wheelSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.WHcolour;
    cxt.fill();
    //draw wheel 2
    cxt.beginPath();

    cxt.arc(this.x * 1.8, this.y, this.wheelSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.WHcolour;
    cxt.fill();
    //draw body 
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.rect(this.x * 0.9, this.y * 0.65, this.carW, this.carH);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.Ccolour
    cxt.fill();
    //draw window1  
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.rect(this.x * 1.615, this.y * 0.69, this.windowW, this.windowH);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.Wcolour;
    cxt.fill();
    //draw window 2
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.rect(this.x * 1.0461, this.y * 0.69, this.windowW * 2.4, this.windowH);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.Wcolour;
    cxt.fill();
  }

  move() {
    //velocity increasment
    //wheels
    this.x += this.direction;
    //body
  }
}

function createCar() {
  while (cars.length < 1) {
    let c = new Car({
      //wheels
      WHcolour: "black",
      x: 130, y: 160, wheelSize: 15,
      //body
      carW: 130, carH: 50, Ccolour: "yellow",
      //windows
      windowW: 25, windowH: 15, Wcolour: "blue",
      //car number 
      carNum: 1,
    });
    cars.push(c)
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you are multiplying this.x by a different number for each part of the car. That could be causing an exponential change in x axis for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can not multiply on the same axis of your movement, you can make the part relative to each other by adding an offset, as you build more complex object multiplication can be used for something that you will launch from the car, like a rocket that will accelerate relative to the position of the car.

Here is your code working

```js
class Car {
  constructor(p) {
    //moving everything 
    this.direction = p.direction || 1;

    //wheel constructor
    this.x = p.x || 130;
    this.y = p.y || 160;
    this.wheelSize = p.wheelSize || 15;
    this.WHcolour = p.WHcolour || "black";

    //body constructor
    this.carW = p.carW || 130;
    this.carH = p.carH || 50;
    this.Ccolour = p.Ccolour || "red";
    //window constructor 
    this.windowW = p.windowW || 25;
    this.windowH = p.windowH || 15;
    this.Wcolour = p.Wcolour || "blue";

    //car number 
    this.carNum = p.carNum || 1;
  }
  
  draw() {
    //draw wheel 1
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.arc(this.x, this.y, this.wheelSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.WHcolour;
    cxt.fill();
    //draw wheel 2
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.arc(this.x + 90, this.y, this.wheelSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.WHcolour;
    cxt.fill();
    //draw body 
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.rect(this.x - 20 , this.y * 0.65, this.carW, this.carH);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.Ccolour
    cxt.fill();
    //draw window1  
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.rect(this.x + 70, this.y * 0.69, this.windowW, this.windowH);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.Wcolour;
    cxt.fill();
    //draw window 2
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.rect(this.x - 10, this.y * 0.69, this.windowW * 2.4, this.windowH);
    cxt.fillStyle = this.Wcolour;
    cxt.fill();
  }

  move() {
    //velocity increasment
    //wheels
    this.x += this.direction;
    //body
  }
}

function createCar() {
  while (cars.length < 1) {
    let c = new Car({
      //wheels
      WHcolour: "black",
      x: 130, y: 160, wheelSize: 15,
      //body
      carW: 130, carH: 50, Ccolour: "yellow",
      //windows
      windowW: 25, windowH: 15, Wcolour: "blue",
      //car number 
      carNum: 1,
    });
    cars.push(c)
  }
}

function move() {
  cxt.clearRect(0,0, 800,800)
  for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    cars[i].draw()
    cars[i].move()
  }
}

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 800;
let cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var cars = []
createCar()
setInterval(move, 100);
```